# RequiredFieldValidator and ListSearchExtender together cause javascript error

Tags: asp.net, listbox, internet-explorer-9, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a ListBox which have both RequriedFieldValidator and ListSearchExtender. But whenever I change the selection of the ListBox and click anywhere in the page, a JavaScript error occurs. The function that throws the error is ValidatorOnChange, the event is null. This is only happens on IE9. If I turn on the Compatibility View, the error disappears. Does anyone have the same problem? Following is my code:

```
<tr>
                <td class="greenback">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    Product <span class="littlefont">*</span>                    
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator10"  
      ControlToValidate="productNamesListBox"
      Text="Required Field!" 
      runat="server" CssClass="warning" ValidationGroup="formValidation"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="productNamesListBox" runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="productNamesSqlDataSource" DataTextField="ProductName" CssClass="listboxes"
                        DataValueField="ProductID" Rows="1" 
                        ondatabound="productNamesListBox_DataBound"></asp:ListBox>
                    <asp:ListSearchExtender ID="productNamesListBox_ListSearchExtender" 
                        runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="productNamesListBox">
                    </asp:ListSearchExtender>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="productNamesSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SPRConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT productID, ProductName FROM [spr2].[dbo].[sprProducts] ORDER by ProductName">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you got yourself a buggy combination.
The simplest way would be to validate on the server end.
This may be costly, hope your server is tough enough.